# stuck on date function in Presto SQL

Tags: sql, presto

I'm stuck on the date function in my code:

```
try(date_parse(min(MilestoneDate), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) >  CURRENT_DATE
```

The message error is : generic internal error.  I don't know what it means. 
If I comment out the 'try(date_parse(min(MilestoneDate), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) >  CURRENT_DATE', the whole code works. But I really need it based on the requirement. I also try: having DATE(SUBSTR(min(finishdate), 1, 10)) > CURRENT_DATE. But the error message is : can't cast to date. Please help. Thank you.

```
With ManagementView1 as (

select * from Management_View a


left join


(select *
 from

(select projectobjectid, id as activity_id,finishdate as MilestoneDate, name as Milestone
 from activity 
 where date = (select max(date) from activity)
 union ALL 
 select projectobjectid, id as activity_id, min(finishdate) as finishdate, 
 name
 from activity 
 where id in ('FS1000', 'PR1000', 'PR1500')

 group by projectobjectid, id, name)
) b

ON  try_cast(a.objectid as double) = b.projectobjectid 
 AND a.id = b.activity_id 
)    

select * from

    (
        select site, building, id, milestonetype, MilestoneDate, Milestone 
         from ManagementView1

         WHERE  milestonetype in ('Breakground', 'Energization')

        UNION ALL 

       select site, building, id, milestonetype, min(MilestoneDate) as 
        MilestoneDate,  Milestone

        from ManagementView1 

        where milestonetype = 'PR'

       having try(date_parse(min(MilestoneDate), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) > 
       CURRENT_DATE


       --having DATE(SUBSTR(min(finishdate), 1, 10)) > CURRENT_DATE

         -- and milestonetype = 'PR'
        group by site, building, id, milestonetype, Milestone


    ) c
```

Comment: What do the values that do not work look like?  Why are you storing a date/time value as a string?

Comment: I tried your solution, and also I modified the sql a bit. It works now. But there is another problem. The data I got from the query is only the data from the first part above 'UNION ALL' ( those belone to 'Breakground' and 'Energization'). I can't get the data from the second part below 'UNION ALL'. Below is the modified query:

Comment: "generic internal error." -- what was the actual message and/or stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `try()` works with `date_parse()` -- even if it does, it does not catch all error. But it should work with `cast()`.  So, try this:

```
DATE(SUBSTR(MIN(finishdate), 1, 10))

MIN(TRY(CAST(SUBSTR(MilestoneDate, 1, 10) as date))) > CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: I tried your solution. It works now. But there is another problem. The data I got from the query is only the data from the first part above 'UNION ALL' . I can't get the data from the second part below 'UNION ALL'.

Comment: select * from  ( select site, building, id, milestonetype, MilestoneDate, Milestone from ManagementView1 WHERE  milestonetype in('Breakground''Energization')
 UNION ALL 
 select site, building, id, milestonetype, min(MilestoneDate) as MilestoneDate,  Milestone from ManagementView1  where milestonetype = 'PR'
 group by site, building, id, milestonetype, Milestone  having min(TRY(cast(Substr(milestoneDate, 1, 10) as DATE))) > CURRENT_DAT ) c

Comment: I used : trim(MilestoneType) = 'PR'. It works now. But the problem is that I want to get the min(MilestoneDate) in the below "UNION ALL" ( in PR category), also the min(MilestoneDate) must be greater than today, and closest to today. Right now, I still get multiple MilestoneDates in PR category. Is there any solution to get this result? Thank you.

Comment: `try` works with functions just as well as with `cast`s (https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#try). In fact, `try_cast` is just a syntactic sugar for `try(cast(...))`. However, by design `try` does not catch all possible failure conditions, so it's is possible it also doesn't catch some failures where it should.

Comment: @Nancy . . . This question is about your attempt to parse the date.  If you have another question, ask it as a *new* question.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I'll post another new question.